# Can I write a literal initializer in Java for a non-primitive type?

Tags: java, literals

Java's literal initializers are mostly used for primitives (e.g. `int i = 2` and `double j = 4.2`), but there are certain non-primitive classes that also have literal initializers (e.g. `String a = "Hello"` or `Number z = 43`). I am looking to implement an initializer similar to that in a class that I wrote. I have a class `Numeric` that extends `Number`, that I would like to be able to initialize as `Numeric a = 43`. Is there any way that this can be done in Java, and if so, how?

Here is the part of the source code for `Numeric`

```
public class Numeric extends Number {

    private HashMap<Primitive, Number> values;
    private Primitive origin;

    public Numeric(byte value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, (short) value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, (int) value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, (long) value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, (float) value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, (double) value);
        origin = Primitive.BYTE;
    }

    public Numeric(short value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, (byte) value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, (int) value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, (long) value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, (float) value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, (double) value);
        origin = Primitive.SHORT;
    }

    public Numeric(int value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, (byte) value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, (short) value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, (long) value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, (float) value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, (double) value);
        origin = Primitive.INT;
    }

    public Numeric(long value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, (byte) value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, (short) value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, (int) value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, (float) value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, (double) value);
        origin = Primitive.LONG;
    }

    public Numeric(float value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, (byte) value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, (short) value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, (int) value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, (long) value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, (double) value);
        origin = Primitive.FLOAT;
    }

    public Numeric(double value) {
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(Primitive.BYTE, (byte) value);
        values.put(Primitive.SHORT, (short) value);
        values.put(Primitive.INT, (int) value);
        values.put(Primitive.LONG, (long) value);
        values.put(Primitive.FLOAT, (float) value);
        values.put(Primitive.DOUBLE, value);
        origin = Primitive.DOUBLE;
    }
```

`Primitive` is just a basic `enum` with all the primitive types.

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` literals as a special case in Java. `Number`s don't really have literals - what you're seeing here is a primitive (such as 2) being autoboxed to its wrapper class (such as `Integer`). Since all the numeric wrappers extends `Number`, this assignments works (in the same way that `Object o = 4;` would be a legal statement).

You can not add your own literals to the language, though. The best you could do is to create some static function that produces a new instance of your class.

Comment: As `Numeric` extends `Number` is there any way I can mess around with auto-boxing in my favor or am I out of luck there too?

Comment: @EliSadoff you're still out of luck. The wrapper classes will be siblings of your new `Numeric` class, so a primitive literal can't be automagically converted to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  There is no way whatsoever to initialize a value other than a primitive or a `String` like you want.